# diffeomorphisms preserve zero measure

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Suppose $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ is an open set and $f:\Omega\rightarrow f(\Omega)$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism. Show that if $F \subset \Omega$ has zero measure then $f(F)$ has zero measure.

---

I know that the following theorem holds:

> Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ be an open set and $f:\Omega\rightarrow f(\Omega)$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism. Suppose $\bar E \subset \Omega$ is compact and suppose $E$ is a measurable set. Then $f(E)$ is measurable and:
>
> $$m(f(E))=\int_E|\det f'(x)|d m(x)$$

Therefore, I know that what I want holds if $\bar F\subset \Omega$ and if $\bar F$ is a compact set. For the general case, I was thinking about trying to get some $F_n$ such that each $\bar F_n \subset \Omega$ is a compact set and such that $F \subset \bigcup_n F_n$, but I don't think that it's going to work.

Comment: Why do you think it's not going to work? [It does work, if you make the right choices.]

Comment: I was tried to make some wrong choices for some time and I gave up, but after seeing Harald's answer it looks really easy now. I will keep this trick in mind.

Comment: Do keep that in mind. It is useful incredibly often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Try $$F_n=\{x\in\Omega\colon |x|\le n\text{ and } \operatorname{dist}(x,\mathbb{R^N}\setminus\Omega)\ge 1/n\}.$$